# What is the alternative of String.Contains() method in J2ME?

Tags: java-me

I want to compare if string1 "stack" is in string2 "Welcome to stack overflow".
How to achieve this in J2ME?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.contains() is worked for that. Why are you looking for alternative? But here is the same code which achieves if a string contains a substring;

```
if( string.indexOf("stack") >= 0 ) { // True

}else {

}
```

In anywhere of `string`, that search the "stack" and returns true or false.

Comment: J2ME doesn't have the String.contains() method, that's why Adilwaheed was looking for an alternative way